# Date Time day of the week comparison logic in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime

Date Time objects allow us to perform actions like this:

```
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$TextDate = get-date -date "02/10/2016"

if ($TextDate -lt $CurrentDate){
    Write-Host "True"
}
else {
    Write-Host "False"
}
```

This outputs "True" because $TextDate is less than $CurrentDate.

Following the same logic, why does the following code output false?

```
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -UFormat %V
$TextDate = Get-Date -date "02/10/2016"
$TextDate = Get-Date -date $TextDate -UFormat %V

if ($TextDate -lt $CurrentDate){
    Write-Host "True"
}
else {
    Write-Host "False"
}
```

The only difference is that we are comparing the week of the year. If you change the comparison to `-gt`, the code returns True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatted dates are strings, not integers.  The string `"6"` is after the string `"11"`.

This would be the most correct way to do this:

First, decide what the "first week of the year" actually means:

```
$CalendarWeekRule = [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstDay;
#$CalendarWeekRule = [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFourDayWeek;
#$CalendarWeekRule = [System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule]::FirstFullWeek;
```

Then, decide which day of the week is the first day of the week:

```
$FirstDayOfWeek = [System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday;
#$FirstDayOfWeek = [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday;
#Any day is available
```

Then you can get your correct week number:

```
$Today = (Get-Date).Date;
$TodayWeek = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($Today, $CalendarWeekRule, $FirstDayOfWeek);

$TargetDate = Get-Date -Date "2016-02-10";
$TargetWeek = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($TargetDate, $CalendarWeekRule, $FirstDayOfWeek);

if ($TargetWeek -lt $TodayWeek) { $true } else { $false }
```

Note that if you want a full ISO 8601 week, it's [somewhat more complicated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net/).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are comparing `string`-objects.

```
(Get-Date -UFormat %V).GetType().FullName
System.String
```

When comparing strings using `-gt` and `-lt` it sorts the strings and because 6 comes after 1, your `6 -lt 11`-test returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Both $TextDate and $CurrentDate are of type [string] so what you are evaluating is '6' -lt '11' which will return false. Operators are based on the left side type in PowerShell. So in order to force an integer comparison modify your expression as under

```
if ([int]$TextDate -lt $CurrentDate)
{ 
   Write-Host "True" 
} 
else 
{
   Write-Host "False" 
}
```