# Why is `-lt` behaving differently for chars and strings?

Tags: powershell, comparison, operators, string-comparison

I recently [answered a SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924619/powershell-date-time-day-of-the-week-comparison-logic/35924960#35924960) about using `-lt` or `-gt` with strings. My answer was based on [something I've read earlier](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-comparison-operators-eq-lt-gt-contains-like-match/) which said that `-lt` compares one char from each string at a time until a ASCII-value is not equal to the other. At that point the result (lower/equal/greater) decides. By that logic, `"Less" -lt "less"` should return `True` because `L` has a lower ASCII-byte-value than `l`, but it doesn't:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("Less".ToCharArray())
76
101
115
115

[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("less".ToCharArray())
108
101
115
115

"Less" -lt "less"
False
```

It seems that I may have been missing a crucial piece: the test is case-insensitive

```
#L has a lower ASCII-value than l. PS doesn't care. They're equal
"Less" -le "less"
True

#The last s has a lower ASCII-value than t. PS cares.
"Less" -lt "lest"
True

#T has a lower ASCII-value than t. PS doesn't care
"LesT" -lt "lest"
False

#Again PS doesn't care. They're equal
"LesT" -le "lest"
True
```

I then tried to test char vs single-character-string:

```
[int][char]"L"
76

[int][char]"l"
108


#Using string it's case-insensitive. L = l
"L" -lt "l"
False

"L" -le "l"
True

"L" -gt "l"
False

#Using chars it's case-sensitive! L < l
([char]"L") -lt ([char]"l")
True

([char]"L") -gt ([char]"l")
False
```

For comparison, I tried to use the case-sensitive less-than operator, but it says `L > l` which is the opposite of what `-lt` returned for chars.

```
"L" -clt "l"
False

"l" -clt "L"
True
```

How does the comparison work, because it clearly isn't by using ASCII-value and why does it behave differently for chars vs. strings?

Comment: BTW, comparison operators are not only case-insensitive by default (which is clearly documented in [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847759.aspx) help topic), but also do proper comparison of composite characters in different forms: `'ё' -eq 'Ё'`.

Comment: Good point. The fact that operators are case-insensitive by default was what led me to test that first, but considering that `-lt` doesn't have a case-sensitive operator like `clike`, `cmatch` etc. it wasn't 100% obvious it should be case-insensitive. Actually `-clt`, `-ilt` etc. exists (undocumented) but they return the same as `-lt` as far as I can tell. Guessing they're just aliases.

Comment: *By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive. To make a comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a "c". For example, the case-sensitive version of "-eq" is "-ceq". To make the case-insensitivity explicit, precede the operator with an "i". For example, the explicitly case-insensitive version of "-eq" is "-ieq".* That is from the link from my previous comment. So, `-clt` and `-ilt` are documented. And them also return different results: `'A'-cle'a'` and `'A'-ile'a'`.

Comment: Getting late here I see so I missed that. :-) `"L" -clt "l"` still doesn't work though.

Comment: I did myself a favor and split them into two SO-questions as it got too complex. The `trace-command` part is moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099167/trace-debug-powershell-operators

Comment: `System.Char` is just special numeric type. So, it compared as numeric not as string. For example: `'AaBb'.GetEnumerator()|sort -CaseSensitive` return `A`, `B`, `a`, `b`; while `'A','a','B','b'|sort -CaseSensitive` return `a`, `A`, `b`, `B`. And string comparison is not work in char by char basis: `&{$a='A','a','B','b';foreach($b in $a){foreach($c in $a){$b+$c}}}|sort -CaseSensitive` — this place `AA` before `ab`, although `a` placed before `A` when go alone.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why char vs string behaves differently as you confirm that char comparison is done using int-values like I expected. Still wondeing how it compares the strings behind-the-scenes. Do you know? And how I can I find the proof myself? And as usual, I would appreciate if you provided this as an answer. :-)

Comment: I've found that `Sort-Object` (after peeling off 100 layers) uses `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture.CompareInfo.Compare()` which uses `String.Compare()`, but that is not a valid answer as I'm interested in `-lt`/`-gt`. They probably works the same as sort, but I want proof. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A big thank-you to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for all his invaluable input.*

**tl; dr**:

- `-lt` and `-gt` compare `[char]` instances *numerically* by *Unicode codepoint*.

  - Confusingly, so do `-ilt`, `-clt`, `-igt`, `-cgt` - even though they only make sense with *string* operands, but that's a quirk in the PowerShell language itself (see bottom).
- `-eq` (and its alias `-ieq`), by contrast, compare `[char]` instances *case-insensitively*, which is typically, but *not necessarily* like a case-insensitive *string* comparison (`-ceq` again compares *strictly numerically*).

  - `-eq`/`-ieq` *ultimately* also compares *numerically*, but first converts the operands to their uppercase equivalents using the invariant culture; as a result, this comparison is not fully equivalent to PowerShell's *string* comparison, which additionally recognizes so-called compatible sequences (distinct characters or even sequences considered to have the same meaning; see [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)) as equal.
  - In other words: **PowerShell *special-cases* the behavior of *only* `-eq` / `-ieq` with `[char]` operands**, and does so in a manner that is **almost, but not quite the same as case-insensitive *string* comparison**.
- This distinction leads to counter-intuitive behavior such as `[char] 'A' -eq [char] 'a'` and `[char] 'A' -lt [char] 'a'` *both* returning `$true`.
- To be safe:

  - always cast to `[int]` if you want *numeric* (Unicode codepoint) comparison.
  - always cast to `[string]` if you want *string* comparison.

For background information, read on.

---

PowerShell's usually helpful operator overloading can be tricky at times.

Note that in a ***numeric* context** (whether implicit or explicit), PowerShell treats **characters (`[char]` (`[System.Char]`) instances)** **numerically**, by their ***Unicode* codepoint** (not *ASCII*).

```
[char] 'A' -eq 65  # $true, in the 'Basic Latin' Unicode range, which coincides with ASCII
[char] 'Ā' -eq 256 # $true; 0x100, in the 'Latin-1 Supplement' Unicode range
```

What makes **`[char]`** unusual is that its instances are **compared to each other *numerically as-is*, by Unicode codepoint, EXCEPT with `-eq`/`-ieq`**.

- `ceq`, `-lt`, and `-gt` compare *directly* by Unicode codepoints, and - counter-intuitively - so do `-ilt`, `-clt`, `-igt` and `-cgt`:

```
[char] 'A' -lt [char] 'a'  # $true; Unicode codepoint 65 ('A') is less than 97 ('a')
```

- `-eq` (and its alias `-ieq`) *first transforms the characters to uppercase*, then compares the resulting Unicode codepoints:

```
[char] 'A' -eq [char] 'a' # !! ALSO $true; equivalent of 65 -eq 65
```

It's worth reflecting on this Buddhist turn: this *and* that: **in the world of PowerShell, character 'A' is both less than *and* equal to 'a', depending on how you compare**.

Also, **directly or indirectly - after transformation to uppercase - comparing Unicode codepoints is NOT the same as comparing them as *strings***, because PowerShell's *string* comparison *additionally* recognizes so-called compatible sequences, where characters (or even character sequences) are considered "the same" if they have the same *meaning* (see [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)); e.g.:

```
# Distinct Unicode characters U+2126 (Ohm Sign) and U+03A9 Greek Capital Letter Omega)
# ARE recognized as the "same thing" in a *string* comparison:
"Ω" -ceq "Ω"  # $true, despite having distinct Unicode codepoints

# -eq/ieq: with [char], by only applying transformation to uppercase, the results
# are still different codepoints, which - compared numerically - are NOT equal:
[char] 'Ω' -eq [char] 'Ω' # $false: uppercased codepoints differ

# -ceq always applies direct codepoint comparison.
[char] 'Ω' -ceq [char] 'Ω' # $false: codepoints differ
```

Note that **use of prefixes `i` or `c` to *explicitly* specify case-matching behavior is NOT sufficient to force *string* comparison**, even though *conceptually* operators such as `-ceq`, `-ieq`, `-clt`, `-ilt`, `-cgt`, `-igt` only make sense with strings.

**Effectively, the `i` and `c` prefixes are simply *ignored* when applied to `-lt` and `-gt` while comparing `[char]` operands**; as it turns out (unlike what I originally thought), this is a **general PowerShell pitfall** - see below for an explanation.

As an aside: **`-lt` and `-gt` logic in *string* comparison is *not* numeric, but based on *collation order*** (a *human*-centric way of ordering independent of codepoints / byte values), which in .NET terms is controlled by *cultures* (either by default by the one currently in effect, or by passing a culture *parameter* to methods).
As @PetSerAl demonstrates in a comment (and unlike what I originally claimed), **PS string comparisons use the *invariant* culture**, not the *current* culture, so their behavior is the same, irrespective of what culture is the current one.

---

**Behind the scenes:**

As @PetserAl explains in the comments, PowerShell's *parsing* doesn't distinguish between the base form of an operator its `i`-prefixed form; e.g., both `-lt` and `-ilt` are translated to the *same* value, `Ilt`.
Thus, **Powershell *cannot* implement *differing* behavior for `-lt` vs. `-ilt`, `-gt` vs. `igt`, ...**, because it treats them the same at the syntax level.

This leads to somewhat **counter-intuitive behavior in that operator prefixes are effectively *ignored* when comparing data types where case-sensitivity has no meaning** - as opposed to getting coerced to strings, as one might expect; e.g.:

```
"10" -cgt "2"  # $false, because "2" comes after "1" in the collation order

10 -cgt 2  # !! $true; *numeric* comparison still happens; the `c` is ignored.
```

In the latter case I would have expected the use of `-cgt` to coerce the operands to strings, given that case-sensitive comparison is only a meaningful concept in string comparison, but that is NOT how it works.

If you want to dig deeper into how PowerShell operates, see @PetSerAl's comments below.

Comment: Is there any benefit to references the .NET sources regarding char and string here to correlate how PowerShell is returning resutls? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,b0e89607f165d052 and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,b42f029a93d6432a

Comment: @KoryGill: Thanks for the links, but I think the behavior described is really on the PowerShell side. (I'm inferring that from the examples I have given; I have not tried to trace execution or dig into the source code). If something doesn't ring true, do tell me.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. I now understand how the chars compares (int comparison). About the last part using char and `-clt` etc. To verify: you expected the comparison of the chars to behave like strings because `-clt/-ilt` only work with strings, right? Still having some trouble with strings though. Where can I find the "collation order" for my culture? Are strings compared with `-lt/-gt` affected by culture even though it's case-insensitive? `"Āa" -cgt "Aa"` is True. Apparently, accented-A is greater than A. Why?

Comment: @FrodeF.: Yes, I expect `-ilt`, `-clt`, ... to force a string comparison, because that's the only meaningful interpretation.
Think of collation order as telephone directory-style sorting: it is independent of codepoints and instead focuses on how _humans_ order (sort) strings,
which typically means grouping uppercase and lowercase letters together, as well as grouping letters together that share the same base letter and differ only by diacritics (e.g., "A" and "Ä").
This is a complex topic, and you should probably ask a separate question if this doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: @FrodeF.: `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.CompareInfo` and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.sortkey.aspx may get you started.

Comment: @FrodeF. If you think about decompiling some PowerShell code, then good point to start would be `System.Management.Automation.Language.PSBinaryOperationBinder.CompareXX` methods. This methods ends up calling `BinaryComparisonCommon` for numeric comparison, `BinaryEqualityComparison` for non-numeric equality comparison and `BinaryComparision` for non-numeric relative comparison. `BinaryEqualityComparison` have special case for comparing `char`s in case-insensitive manner. There is no special case for `char` in `BinaryComparision`, it just ends up calling `IComparable.CompareTo`.

Comment: @mklement0 As of PS v5, both `BinaryEqualityComparison` and `BinaryComparision` specifically use `InvariantCulture`, when comparing strings, not `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture`: `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture='tr'; [string]::Equals('i','I','CurrentCultureIgnoreCase'); 'i'-ieq'I'`. Also `System.Management.Automation.Language.TokenKind` enum does not have special values for non-prefixed comparison operators: `{$a-eq$b}.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].Expression.Operator` — return `Ieq`, so it would be kind of problematic to provide different behavior `-ilt` vs `-lt`.

Comment: Thanks for great comments as usual! :) Can I ask how you found ex:`System.Management.Automation.Language.PSBinaryOperationBinder.CompareXX` did you just look around/search in libraies or did you use a powershell command/property of some sort (like `ast` etc.) to get you on the right tracK?

Comment: @FrodeF. I start from `System.Management.Automation.Language.Compiler.VisitBinaryExpression`. From here I got to `PSBinaryOperationBinder` class. Then I inspect base class `BinaryOperationBinder.Bind` method. It call `DynamicMetaObject.BindBinaryOperation` method. Which, if not overridden, call back to `BinaryOperationBinder.FallbackBinaryOperation` method. So, I inspect `PSBinaryOperationBinder.FallbackBinaryOperation`. And here we already have all the `CompareXX` methods.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Thanks for corrections and great background info, I've substantially revised the answer - let me know if something still looks off.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes `-ceq` applied to `[char]` operands do numeric comparison, but it not always yield same results as in string semantic: `'Ω' -ceq 'Ω'` vs. `[char]'Ω' -ceq [char]'Ω'`. (`U+2126` *Ohm Sign* vs. `U+03A9` *Greek Capital Letter Omega*)

Comment: Thanks again, @PetSerAl - answer updated. Now that the fog has cleared in my head, I conclude: (a) not forcing string semantics with `i` and `c`-prefixed operators is counter-intuitive (though I now understand why that's not an option), 
and (b) special-casing `-eq` / `-eq` for `[char]` was an unfortunate design decision. I sincerely appreciate your ability to illustrate your points with succinct code snippets.

Comment: `-ieq` also use numeric comparison when comparing `char`s, but it apply `[char]::ToUpperInvariant` to both operands to do it in case-insensitive manner. You can use the same *Ohm/Omega* snippet to see that. So, in terms of `[System.StringComparison]` you can say, when comparing `char`s, `-ieq` and `-ine` use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` comparison, while all other operators use `Ordinal` comparison; when comparing strings `i` prefixed operators use `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, while `c` prefixed use `InvariantCulture` comparison; when comparing something else prefix ignored/not used.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what to post here other than the comparisons are all correct when dealing with strings/characters.  If you want an Ordinal comparison, do an Ordinal comparison and you get results based on that.

[Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx)

```
[string]::Compare('L','l')
returns 1
```

and

```
[string]::Compare("L","l", [stringcomparison]::Ordinal)
returns -32
```

Not sure what to add here to help clarify.

Also see: [Upper vs Lower Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See updated question as I cleaned it up a bit. I don't want to specify the comparison method, I just want to understand how `-lt`/`-gt` works by default, because `"L" -lt "l"` (False because equal) does not return the same as `([char]"L") -lt ([char]"l")` (True). If operators by default are case-insensitive, shouldn't both return `False` because they are equal?