# Powershell if -eq and -ieq are case in-sensitive and serves same purpose or -ieq needs to be used in specific scenario?

Tags: powershell, operators, case-sensitive

```
if ("True" -eq "true") {
  Write-Host "Hello"
} 
else {
  Write-Host "World"
}
```

Output:
"Hello"

```
if ("True" -ieq "true") {
  Write-Host "Hello"
} 
else {
  Write-Host "World"
}
```

Output:
"Hello"

If both serve the same purpose, is there any need for `-ieq`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Operator `-ieq` is just an *alias* (another name) for `-eq`**, the [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq)<sup>[1]</sup>, which is **case-*insensitive* for string comparisons, as PowerShell generally is**.

As such, `-ieq` isn't strictly needed, but you may choose to use it to explicitly signal case-insensitivity (which the `i` indicates), and to contrast it with the `-ceq` variant of the `-eq` operator, which is case-*sensitive* (which the `c` indicates).

**Caveat**: `i`- and `c`-prefixed variants exist for *all* comparison operands, (e.g., `-imatch` / `-cmatch`), but **for operators such as `-eq` that also work with operands *other than strings*, the use of a prefix is *ignored* for *non-string* operands**; e.g., `1 -ceq 1` and `1 -ieq 1` are the same as `1 -eq 1` and simply compare *numerically*.
**`[char]` comparison is a *hybrid* case**: with `-eq` variants it *mostly* acts like with *strings* (case-insensitive, culture-invariant comparison, but, unlike with strings, Unicode equivalence between character is *not* recognized), whereas with `-lt` / `-gt` variants it strictly performs *ordinal* comparison, i.e. *numerical* comparison by Unicode *code point* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105274/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Technically speaking, behind the scenes, it is the other way around:

`{ 'True' -eq 'true' }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].Expression.Operator` yields `Ieq`.</sup>